# Power adapter extender for iPhone

Tags: iphone

Imagine the disappointment when trying to pair a [Monster iCar Play 800 FM Transmitter](http://www.monstercable.com/productdisplay.asp?pin=5147) with a new iPhone comfortably wrapped in a [Speck CandyShell](http://www.speckproducts.com/iphone/iphone-4/candyshell-1408.html).  In short, the business end of one does not fit into the business end of the other.

I've looked at the [SendStation Dock Extender](http://www.sendstation.com/us/products/dockextender/), but is there really any guarantee that this will fit into my case.

Does anyone have any experience with this or another dock extender, or is my best option to be more careful when buying a replacement case?

**Edit:**

I ended up buying an adapter by [Cable Jive](http://www.cablejive.com/products/dockStubz.html).  It fits the case and works just fine.

Comment: TGnat your own advice is always a good idea when buying things :)

Comment: @TGnat Note that you should not edit your answer into the question, instead you should answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @TGnat Just a reminder, you should answer the question with an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Just eyeballing it, it looks like the extender would fit. If not, maybe take a Dremel to that case and widen the slot?